# Postfix: can't send mail from remote client

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'm having issues sending mail from postfix. I believe my conf. is very standard, at the end it was put together from various guides. I'm trying to send mail from remote client (iOS Mail, and Mac OS X Mail.app, Thunderbird on Linux). From iOS Mail it works ok, it does not for Mail.app and Thunderbird. I'm using SASL authentication (dovecot), and TLS, configuration below along with log message.

Error:

```
Jan 05 12:27:41 svali postfix/smtpd[26448]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from aaa.chello.sk[89.173.206.108]: 553 5.7.1 <xxx>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user xxx; from=<xxx> to=<yyy> proto=ESMTP helo=<[10.0.2.4]>
Jan 05 12:27:41 svali postfix/smtpd[26448]: disconnect from aaa.chello.sk[89.173.206.108]
Jan 05 12:31:01 svali postfix/anvil[26450]: statistics: max connection rate 2/60s for (submission:89.173.206.108) at Jan  5 12:24:33
```

When it works (iOS Mail app)

```
Jan 05 12:45:23 svali postfix/smtpd[26807]: connect from aaa.chello.sk[89.173.206.108]
Jan 05 12:45:24 svali postfix/smtpd[26807]: 1328056578: client=aaa.chello.sk[89.173.206.108], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=xxx
Jan 05 12:45:24 svali postfix/cleanup[26821]: 1328056578: message-id=<42EC179A-DE92-4526-9F0E-DA3B5EF76B80@aaa>
Jan 05 12:45:24 svali postfix/qmgr[2599]: 1328056578: from=<xxx>, size=650, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 05 12:45:24 svali postfix/smtp[26824]: 1328056578: to=<yyy>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c05::1a]:25, delay=0.71, delays=0.17/0.01/0.04/0.49, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1388925924 f3si3608555wik.58 - gsmtp)
Jan 05 12:45:24 svali postfix/qmgr[2599]: 1328056578: removed
Jan 05 12:45:26 svali postfix/smtpd[26827]: connect from mail-qe0-f42.google.com[209.85.128.42]
Jan 05 12:45:27 svali postfix/smtpd[26827]: 28DA856578: client=mail-qe0-f42.google.com[209.85.128.42]
Jan 05 12:45:27 svali postfix/cleanup[26821]: 28DA856578: message-id=<42EC179A-DE92-4526-9F0E-DA3B5EF76B80@aaa>
Jan 05 12:45:27 svali postfix/qmgr[2599]: 28DA856578: from=<yyy+caf_=dusan=xxx>, size=2535, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 05 12:45:27 svali postfix/smtpd[26827]: disconnect from mail-qe0-f42.google.com[209.85.128.42]
Jan 05 12:45:28 svali dovecot[26832]: lda(xxx): sieve: msgid=<42EC179A-DE92-4526-9F0E-DA3B5EF76B80@aaa>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
Jan 05 12:45:28 svali postfix/pipe[26831]: 28DA856578: to=<xxx>, relay=spamass, delay=1.1, delays=0.69/0.01/0/0.36, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamass service)
Jan 05 12:45:28 svali postfix/qmgr[2599]: 28DA856578: removed
```

**main.cf**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/svali.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/svali.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

# Enabling SMTP for authenticated users, and handing off authentication to Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

# Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
# virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_transport = spamass

# Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

# Disable TLS for SMTP connections
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/discard_ehlo

# OpenDKIM
non_smtpd_milters=inet:127.0.0.1:8891
smtpd_milters=inet:127.0.0.1:8891
```

**master.cf**

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_milters=inet:127.0.0.1:8891
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
        -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
spamass   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/vendor_perl/spamc -u ${recipient} -e /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
#  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error

```
Sender address rejected: not owned by user xxx;
```

came from this restriction on submission port (master.cf file)

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  ...
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  ...
```

As explained in [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch),

> reject_sender_login_mismatch
>
> > Reject the request when **$smtpd_sender_login_maps** specifies an owner for the MAIL FROM address, but the client is not (SASL) logged in as that MAIL FROM address owner; or when the client is (SASL) logged in, but the client login name doesn't own the MAIL FROM address according to **$smtpd_sender_login_maps**.

The reason of *iOS Mail works but Mail.app and Thunderbird doesn't* is likely you didn't specified the right sender address when configured mail client.